# Wso2 CEP clustering as Distributed - Exception

Tags: centos, wso2, wso2-cep

I'm following the [sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Sample+0504+-+Processing+a+Distributed+Siddhi+Query+with+Partitioning+by+integrating+with+Apache+Storm) and I got the exception as follow when i try to invoke `./wso2cep-samples.sh -sn 0504` command in terminal. What can i do to get mu app up and run?

> ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.storm.StormTopologyManager}
>   -  TopologySubmitterJob:116, Runtime Exception connecting to storm when trying to check whether topology 'StatExecutionPlan[-1234]' exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by my self. I set false in the `<parameter name="AvoidInitiation">false</parameter>` tag. in conf/axiss/axis2.xml. Then app is work fine.